# Move a method from an interface to another

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, refactoring

I'm trying to move a Kotlin interface method to another existing interface, by refactoring. But a can't find the right option in Android Studio. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

@Lore, We can do that, with following steps. But with this, it seems like the newly created `interface` implements the existing one. So, we just have to delete that implementation in the new `interface` file.

`Select function -> Refactor -> Extract -> Interface... -> Extract to separate file -> Check Move`

Comment: I wanna move to another _existing_ interface... I have edited the question...